# Solution to Singular Integral

Tags: integration, exponential-function, singular-integrals

Does anybody know how to solve the following singular integral:

$$
\int_0^\pi \frac{\text{e}^{-i\cdot a\cdot \cos(x)}}{\cos(x)-b}\,\text{d}x
$$

with $x$, $a$ and $b$ being real-valued.
Do integrals of this general form belong to a specific class of integrals?

The inequality constraint on b is:
$$
\lvert b\rvert\leq1
$$

Comment: Are you familiar with contour integration?

Comment: ${\large \left\vert b\right\vert > 1\ ?}$.

Answer (score 0):

$\displaystyle{%
{\cal I}
\equiv
\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\text{e}^{-{\rm i}a\cos\left(x\right)}}
                   {\cos\left(x\right)-b}\,\text{d}x}$

${\large\mbox{Just a hint !!!}\,:}$
$$
{\cal I}
=
{\rm e}^{-{\rm i}ab}
\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\text{e}^{-{\rm i}a\left\lbrack\cos\left(x\right) - b\right\rbrack}}
                   {\cos\left(x\right)-b}\,\text{d}x
$$

\begin{align}
{\partial\left({\rm e}^{{\rm i}ab}{\cal I}\right) \over \partial a}
=
-{\rm i}{\rm e}^{{\rm i}ab}\int_{0}^{\pi}
\text{e}^{-{\rm i}a\cos\left(x\right)}\,\text{d}x 
=
-{\rm i}{\rm e}^{{\rm i}ab}\ \pi\,{\rm J}_{0}\left(a\right) 
\end{align}

${\rm J}_{0}\left(z\right)$ is a ${\bf\mbox{Bessel function of the first kind}}$.